# How To Start IIS

Tags: powershell, iis

When I run the following:

`$iis = get-wmiobject Win32_Service -ComputerName $env:computername -Filter "name='IISADMIN'`"

I get nothing.

How do I verify that IIS is running in Powershell?
Second, how do I start it, if I determine that it's not running?

Because the above returns nothing, I can only *assume* this means it isn't running, but I have run IISReset and received the output:

> Attempting stop...
>
> Internet services successfully stopped
>
> Attempting start...
>
> Internet services successfully restarted

This implies that it is running, yet the other script indicates that it's not (other script's [source is here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/637615d6-10fa-4482-ac2e-54a6c830ada7/check-if-iis-running-on-a-remote-server?forum=winserverpowershell), and I get a message of "It is not running").

Assuming that it is not running, how do I start IIS with Powershell?

IIS is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the service if stopped,then start it if stopped:

```
$service = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName 'myserver' -Filter "Name='IISAdmin'"
IF($service.State -eq 'Stopped')
{
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName 'myserver' -Filter "Name='IISAdmin'" | Start-Service
"Service started successfully"
}
elseif($service.State -eq 'Running')
{
"Service is already in running state"
}
```

Apart from this, you can check with [Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx).

Hope it helps.